# How would one add the fist number of a new array to the array preceding it to obtain the sum total using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is the first time I have asked a question on here so please bear with me.  I am working on a task that has me totaling up a ten-pin bowling scorecard.  Where I am currently hung up is I am trying to add the total of one array to the first number on the next array and I am unsure about how to go about this.

In essence, a portion of the scorecard reads as follows:

```js
[6, 4], [5, 4]
```

What I am looking to do is obtain the total of the first array (i.e. 10) and then add the first item of the next array to it to give an overall total of 15 which would be the score after a "spare" in bowling.

I have a feeling I would need to be using dot or square bracket notation to achieve this but I am just not sure as I am still pretty fresh to all this.

For reference sake the whole array is as follows:

```js
const frames = [[1, 2], [6, 4], [5, 4], [10, 0], [7, 2], [10, 0], [10, 0], [5, 2], [7, 0], [4, 4]];
```

Please let me know if there is any more detail I should provide, as I say this is all a bit new to me! Thank you for any pointers in advance.

Comment: What's your expected output for the `frames` array?

Comment: I don't quite get what the result is supposed to look like. `[6,4],[5,4] -> [6,4][5,4,10]` ??? What about `frames` where there are more than just two elements?

Comment: Hi @Reyno - the output I would be lookng for is a number as I would be looking to total up the scorecard - hope that helps?

Comment: Do you need a single number or a score per subarray? Please update your question so we can visually see what you mean.

Comment: Hi @NullDev -  so the ```[6,4]``` would add up to 10 - in bowling this means you would add the first number of the next from - in this instance ```[5,4]``` to the total of 10 from the first frame to give you a total of 15.  The resulting output would be a number - I hope that helps?

Answer (score 0):

I've left it a bit messy so you can see what's going on.

```
const frames = [[1, 2],[6, 4],[5, 4],[10, 0],[7, 2],[10, 0],[10, 0],[5, 2],[7, 0],[4, 4],];

const sumArray = frames.map((frame, i) => frame.reduce((curr, acc) => curr + acc) )

for(let i = 1; i < frames.length; i++) {
    frames[i][0] += sumArray[i-1]
}

console.log(frames)
// [ [ 1, 2 ],  [ 9, 4 ],  [ 15, 4 ], [ 19, 0 ],  [ 17, 2 ], [ 19, 0 ,  [ 20, 0 ], [ 15, 2 ],  [ 14, 0 ], [ 11, 4 ] ]
```

Mutating the array isn't the best but hey.

Oh and I don't know bowling but if you want this to be additive just do this:

```
for(let i = 1; i < frames.length; i++) {
    frames[i][0] += frames[i - 1].reduce( ( a, c ) => a + c )
}
```

You'll get

```
[[ 1, 2 ], [ 9, 4 ], [ 18, 4 ], [ 32, 0 ], [ 39, 2 ], [ 51, 0 ], [ 61, 0], [ 66, 2 ], [ 75, 0 ], [ 79, 4 ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const frames = [[1, 2], [6, 4], [5, 4], [10, 0], [7, 2], [10, 0], [10, 0], [5, 2], [7, 0], [4, 4]];

const scores = frames.map((pins, i) => {
  let score = pins[0] + pins[1];
  // You could also use reduce like:
  // let score = pins.reduce((sum, num) => sum + num);
  
  const next = frames[i + 1];
  if(next) {
    score += next[0];
  }
  
  return score;
});

const totalScore = scores.reduce((sum, num) => sum + num);

console.log(totalScore);
console.log(scores);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for coming back to me with this @Reyno - I really appreciate the help!